# How to implement count missing brackets?

Tags: javascript

For example:
I have a string only contains brackets '(' and ')'. How to count missing brackets?

My code:

```
var str = '(())';
var open = 0, close = 0, count = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
  if (str[i] == '(') {
    open++;
    count = Math.abs(open - close);
  } else {
    close++;
    count = Math.abs(open - close);
  }
}
console.log(count);
```

Input: '(())'
Output: 0

Input: '(()'
Output: 1

Input: '))(('
Output: 4

Input: '(()('
Output: 2

Input: '(()()))(())(())'
Output: 1

Comment: nice question, what have you tried?

Comment: Please provide some code of what you have tried so far, otherwise it could be just homework.

Comment: Loop over the characters in the string. For every `(` you encounter, add 1. For every `)` you encounter, subtract 1. The remainder is the number of missing brackets.

Comment: @nbokmans that wouldn't work for `'))(('`

Comment: Hi! Please read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: Yeah, but once it gets negative you know it can't be correct.

Comment: Why is the value for the last one '3'. Shouldn't it be '1'? The only parenthesis lacking its partner is the 7th character

Comment: I updated my code. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the future it would be best to provide what you have tried so far

But I liked the question and here is a snippet showing it working:

The issue is you need to add to the count of 'missing' when an end bracket appears and there are no start brackets to accompany it.

```js
function countMissing(input) {
  let danglingEnds = 0;
  let opened = 0;
  for (const character of input) {
    if (character === '(') opened++;
    else if (character === ')') {
      if (opened === 0) danglingEnds++;
      else opened--;
    }
  }
  return opened + danglingEnds;
}

console.log(countMissing('(())'));
console.log(countMissing('(()'));
console.log(countMissing('))(('));
console.log(countMissing('(()('));
console.log(countMissing('(()()))(())(())'));
```

Answer (score 2):

You could replace perfect brackets and count the rest.

```js
function missing(string) {
    var l;

    do {
        l = string.length;
        string = string.replace(/\(\)/g, '');
    } while (l !== string.length)
 
    return string.length;
}

console.log(missing('(())')); // 0
console.log(missing('(()')); // 1
console.log(missing('))((')); // 4
console.log(missing('(()(')); // 2
console.log(missing('(()()))(())(())')); // 3
```

Comment: This answer is much more elegant than mine

Answer (score 0):

Below code output missing parenthesis count

```js
var missingParenthesisCnt = function(s) {
       var stack = 0, combo=[];
      for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
          var item = s[i];
          if (s[i]=="(") {
            if(stack<0){
                combo.push(Math.abs(stack))
                stack=0
            }
            stack+=1
          } 
          else if(s[i]==")"){
            stack-=1
          }
        }
      return stack + combo.reduce((a,b)=>a+b, 0);
    }
    console.log("Total Missing Parenthesis Count:", missingParenthesisCnt(")))((()"))
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).